# Using pixi-cull library w/ Pixi.js - Getting "Cull is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I'm trying to add `culling` to my Pixi.js application, so I'm following the `Installation` part of this tutorial, https://github.com/davidfig/pixi-cull, and now I'm getting a

`index.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Cull' of undefined at window.onload (index.js:2)`

I've been on this issue for the entire day, and there is absolutely nothing I've found helpful online.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using `Pixi.js` version `PixiJS 6.0.1 - ✰ WebGL 2`

All files along with their `.map` files are in order

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Application</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="preload" href="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="css/styles.css">
        
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pixi.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pixi-cull.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/viewport.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 15px; top: 0;">
            <span id="fps" style="color:black;">0</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = () => {
    var SimpleCull = new PIXI.extras.Cull.Simple();
    
    var app = new PIXI.Application();
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);
    
    // create viewport
    var viewport = new Viewport.Viewport({
        screenWidth: app.view.offsetWidth,
        screenHeight: app.view.offsetHeight,
        worldWidth: 10000,
        worldHeight: 10000
    });

    app.stage.addChild(viewport);
    viewport.drag().pinch().wheel().decelerate().moveCenter(5000, 5000);

    // add red boxes
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        var sprite = viewport.addChild(new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.WHITE));
        sprite.tint = 0xff0000;
        sprite.width = sprite.height = 100
        sprite.position.set(Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000);
    }

    var cull = new Cull.Simple();
    cull.addList(viewport.children);
    cull.cull(viewport.getVisibleBounds());

    // cull whenever the viewport moves
    PIXI.ticker.shared.add(() =>
    {
        if (viewport.dirty)
        {
            cull.cull(viewport.getVisibleBounds());
            viewport.dirty = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't have a variable called `Cull` defined anywhere, which is why `new Cull.Simple();` fails. Follow the advice in my last comment on the old question and set `var Cull = PIXI.extras.Cull`

Comment: The error is on the line `Var SimpleCull = new PIXI.extras.Cull.Simple()`, and believe me I've tried switching it up numerous ways.

It turns out that PIXI.extras is deprecated on this specific instance, and now I'm lost because the documentation doesn't give any sort of solution

This guy has the same issue with no resolve https://github.com/davidfig/pixi-cull/issues/16

Comment: damn, looks like they don't support use without a bundler anymore :(

Comment: Use a game engine they said, why reinvent the wheel they said, it will be easier they said 